# Проверка условия JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять эту запись:

```
if(!this.current_position) {
    this.arrows.left.hide();
}
```

Как понять эту запись `!this.current_position`. Я знаю что `!` это отрицание. Но сама запись не понятна.

Comment: Это обращение к свойству или методу объекта в котором находишься. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: а почему отрицание `!`?

Comment: Если условие вернет `false`, тогда выполнится конструкция внутри.

Comment: `!something` также будет `true` если `something` - false,0,undefined,null или '' (пустая строка).

Comment: может если у кого время есть , посмотрите конкретно в этой функции https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/e9ncjnca/   что эта запись дает?

Comment: @Marina Voronova  Более точно можно сказать, если знать, какие значения присваиваются или хранятся в current_position. Это может быть 0, "", null, undifined и т.д.

Comment: изначально там `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так если вы знаете, что `!` это отрицание не понятно в чем у вас проблема.
В этом коде проверяется:

> Если не текущая позиция (не забыть про приведение типов), то скрыть левую стрелку (видимо у слайдера).

Скорее всего тут проверка на значение `== 0`, то есть такое условие `this.current_position == 0` будет идентично `!this.current_position` в случае типа свойства – `int`

### UPD

Проще говоря, если `this.current_position` равен `0` или такого свойства не существует, то выполняется `this.arrows.left.hide();`